# How to auto-recalculate column cells if values change in preceding column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

Backstory: I built a budget spreadsheet for my personal finances. I calculated my obligations for the month, and the leftovers I want to divy up into specific savings account buckets on a monthly basis. Because my monthly expenses can be variable, I built a simple cell by cell formula method to make sure I'm saving proportionally to what I have available.

Below are the following columns:

**Saving Buckets**: the categories to save for every month
ideal/month: My ideal month's savings. For example, I ideally want to save $200 per month for car repairs/maintenance. Ideally, I want to save up to $3,525 per month total.

**ideal proportion**: taking the ideal savings, making it a proportion of the total goal savings. For example, the car savings is 200/3525 = 0.057

**Multiplier (1 or 0 )** :  So available savings multiplied by ideal proportion multiplied by the multiplier will be the total I want to save in each category. If the multiplier is 0, the category will get no savings for the month. If I don't want to save for vacations this month, I mark vacations as 0.

**Month's Savings**: What I should save for each category based on what I actually have to save. For example, for the month of June, I had $2,987.94 to save, so although I ideally want to save $200 a month, I can only save $169.53 ($2,987.94 * ideal proportion * multiplier).

Now, this sounds very basic, but here's where I run into problems. Let's say, for this upcoming month, that I don't want to save for gifts or car repairs, so I set those with a multiplier of 0. What I then want is all the other buckets to adjust to the reduction of categories. So if I set one or multiple categories to 0, I want those savings distributed to the other buckets proportionally. In other words, I want it to auto-recalculate as soon as I change the multiplier, so that I can know how much to save with the buckets I want to save.

My guess is to adjust the ideal proportion to be a `sumif` function, where if Multiplier is 1, then proportion normally. If 0, then add distribute that proportion to the other buckets, but I haven't found a neat solution to this.

Here's a sample of the table with formulas I used, but was looking for a shorter way to accomplish the same effect because of the number of columns required, as this method isn't exact and doesn't recalculate 100%:

Table Sample :

[image: Table Sample]

Comment: Can you please provide a new screen cap that includes the column labels? it's hard to figure out what the formulas refer to otherwise

Comment: Is `sum(c:c)` = 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the target amount is entered in A1. Put this in L3 :

```
=$A$1/SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$B$12,$C$3:$C$12)*B3*C3
```

and drag downwards. I got :

[image: table]

Idea :

- `$A$1/SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$B$12,$C$3:$C$12)` get the reduced/adjusted
  ratio.
- `B3*C3` 'decides' whether or not to include that line/section
  into the the planned budget.
- The `L3:L12` values will change immediately as the 1/0 in column C is changed.

Please share if it works/understandable/not.